# Constructing a transition matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to construct a stochastic transition matrix. Given a N_by_N matrix M,  M[i,j] is the probability between i and j. The problem is that I need to construct M and what I have to construct M is the following:

- Matrix R , the same as M, except that R[i,j] = 1 if the probability between i and j is > 0. (R is very sparse)
- Function Pr(i,j) that gives the probability between i and j.

So I have R and Pr and I need to construct M. The only way I can think of doing this is with expensive python loops and I'm wondering if there's a fast way to do this with numpy.

Comment: That would probably depend on the implementation of `Pr`. If I understand correctly, you are essentially asking us if `Pr` can be vectorized or not.

Comment: before wondering, please profile your code with the python loops

Comment: @flebool the loop is O(N^2) ... which is super slow!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, `M` will be just as sparse as `R`, (because R[i,j]==1 iff Pr(i,j)>0). Then you need only run `Pr(i,j,)` for the non-zero elements of `R`, which you can get with the numpy `where` function:

```
I,J=where(R)
```

And now your loops are considerably reduced (assuming R is indeed sparse):

```
M=zeros(R.shape)

for i,j in zip(I,J):
    M[i,j]=Pr(i,j)
```

Comment: yeah actually I did something like this. I used np.nonzero()